# How to access tensorflow::Tensor C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I am running Tensorflow using its C++ API.

I have the following call that returns four tensors in finalOutput:

```
        std::string str1 = "detection_boxes";
        std::string str2 = "detection_scores";
        std::string str3 = "detection_classes";
        std::string str4 = "num_detections";

        std::vector<Tensor> finalOutput;
        status = session->Run({ {InputName, inputTensor} }, { str1, str2, str3, str4 }, {}, &finalOutput);
        std::cout << finalOutput[0].DebugString() << std::endl;
```

The print statement outputs the following:

"Tensor<
type: float shape: [1,100,4] values: [[0.00710274419 0.766219556 0.0347728245]]...>"

Now that I have a Tensor with 100 elements and each element has 4 values, how can I iterate through the elements and values?

It seems like I have to call a function to return a Eigen::TensorMap then somehow access the elements.  I am just not sure quite how to do that.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I'm able to do like this

```
// tensor<float, 3>: 3 here because it's a 3-dimension tensor
auto output_detection_boxes = outputs[0].tensor<float, 3>();
std::cout << "detection boxes" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    // using (index_1, index_2, index_3) to access the element in a tensor
    std::cout << output_detection_boxes(0, i, j)
              << "\t";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and here is the output

```
detection boxes
0.0370  0.0465  0.8914  0.3171
0.0924  0.3944  0.9344  0.9769
0.0155  0.2988  0.8812  0.5263
0.1518  0.3817  0.9316  1.0000
0.0000  0.3285  0.8447  0.6669
0.0389  0.2030  0.8504  0.4749
...

(100 in total)
```

Comment: How do you get the detected name?